# WordPress custom post type url change

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, urls

I have two custom post types.

1. Destinations - destination custom post type has their posts and they are organized in hierarchical mode example:

   - Malaga

     - Food
     - Gallery
     - Rooms
   - Marbella

     - Food
     - Gallery
     - Rooms

Each of the destination post it was programmed to look as a page. Inside Rooms post (page) I can select other different custom post types from "Room" custom post type to be visible inside a Room page.

2. Room - custom post type, have their details, price, description etc.
   Now when I am opening one of the destination page and then I click on Room it will open my room page. URL will be something like: `"/rooms/room-name"`.

Now in room page I have all the room custom post types that I have selected.

Now my problem is that when I click on the rooms they will redirect me to custom post type URL example: `"/room/room-name"`.

My question is how can I change the custom post type url, so when I click on room custom post type to not change the actual URL but just to add room title in URL example to be like:

```
"/malaga/rooms/room-name"
```

My problem is that destionation part is dynamic and I don't know how to do that ?

What changes do I need to do to be able to use custom post types in this way ?

Comment: Is the current setup of CPTs set in stone? You could set `rooms` as CPT and use `destination` as a custom taxonomy. This way a permalink like you wish would be much easier to get with the default permalink structure in WordPress

Comment: The website it was programmed to have the destinations and rooms as a separate post types and I cannot change that. I need to do something with url rewriting but I am not totally sure because It is my first time that I have encounter this kind of problem.

Comment: Is it okay to rewrite everything in `/X/rooms/room-name` to the specific room? If not, how do we know `malaga` is a valid value and `marbella` is not? Does every room have a different name/slug?

Comment: One room can be selected in multiple destinations. Each destionation has different slug and name `/marbella` or `malaga`. Each of the destinations has their own rooms page `/marbella/rooms` or `/mallaga/rooms`. In each of the rooms we have "room" custom post type posts selected and when users click on them it should be: `/marbella/rooms/room-1` or `/malaga/rooms/room-1`.