# Rewrite url for custom post type with specific url

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a custom post types called Destinatiosn. These post on click opens as pages  and they are organised hierarchically. Example:

- Malaga

  - Food
  - Gallery
  - Rooms
- Marbella

  - Food
  - Gallery
  - Rooms

Now in Rooms page, I am selecting to use other custom post types called "Room". In this page I will show selected custom post types. But my problem is that when I click on these custom post types URL is changing. I just want to add on existing url only the name of the room.

Example, I am in this page:

```
/marbella/rooms
```

On room custom post type click, I want room to be:

```
/marbella/rooms/room-name
```

But when I click Url changed to:

```
/room/room-name
```

`function add_page_rewrite_rules(){
   $url_path = trim(parse_url(add_query_arg(array()), PHP_URL_PATH), '/');
   $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct( 'room', $url_path . '/%room%', false );
}`

But if I change url to something else working, when I am using example `/malaga` or `/marbella` it is not working and I don't know why ?

How can I resolve my problem ?

My question here is a unique because I have added a sample of code and I do not know why url:

`$wp_rewrite->add_permastruct( 'room', $url_path . '/%room%', false );`

is not working but when I change to some url which does not exist works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WordPress custom post type url change](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/320564/wordpress-custom-post-type-url-change)

Comment: Please, don't add the same question more than once...